# Why doesn't attribute render work in a custom component in JSF 2.0?

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

I'm making a conceptual test with composite components, custom component in JSF 2.0.

The situation is the next:

I have composite component that receives the only attribute slider which it is a Integer.
I have a custom component 'slider' which has a label ajax that caught the custom event 'valueChange
When that event is fired the listener #{myBean.changeInterval} is executed.

But I don't know why the component outputText with id 'grouper' not executed.

I thinks it is a problem with selectors in jsf. But I'm not sure.

Thanks for help!

The composite component.

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"    
xmlns:composite="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite"
xmlns:slider="http:/slider"
xmlns:chart="http:/chart">

<!-- INTERFACE --> 
<composite:interface>
  <composite:attribute name="slider" required="true"/>    
</composite:interface> 

<!-- IMPLEMENATION -->          
<composite:implementation>

                <h:form>

                    <h:inputText value="#{myBean.grouper}">
                        <f:ajax event="keyup"  render=":j_idt33:j_idt56:j_idt57:grouper :out"></f:ajax>
                    </h:inputText>

                    <h:outputText  id="grouper" value="#{myBean.grouper}"   ></h:outputText>

                    <slider:slider slider="#{cc.attrs.slider}" id="slider" >
                            <f:ajax event="valueChange" listener="#{myBean.changeInterval}" render=":j_idt33:j_idt56:j_idt57:grouper :out"    ></f:ajax>
                    </slider:slider>


                </h:form>


</composite:implementation>
```

The custom component.

ClientBehaviorHolder,Serializable {

```
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

protected static final String FAMILY = "slider";
protected static final String RENDERTYPE = "com.component.jsf2.slider.SliderRender";
private   static final String EVENT_VALUE_CHANGE ="valueChange";

enum PropertyKeys {
    slider;

     String toString;
     PropertyKeys(String toString) { this.toString = toString; }
        PropertyKeys() { }
        public String toString() {
            return ((toString != null) ? toString : super.toString());
        }
}

@Override
public String getFamily() {
    return FAMILY;
}
@Override
public String getRendererType() {
    return RENDERTYPE;
}


@Override
public void decode(FacesContext context) {

    Map<String,String> map = context.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
    for (String key : map.keySet()) {
        System.out.println("key : " + key  + " , value  : " + map.get(key));
    }


    ExternalContext external = context.getExternalContext();
    Map<String, String> params = external.getRequestParameterMap();
    String behaviorEvent = params.get("javax.faces.behavior.event");

    if (EVENT_VALUE_CHANGE.equals(behaviorEvent)) {

        String grouper = params.get("grouper");
        if (grouper != null) {
            setSlider(Integer.parseInt(grouper));
        }

    }

    Map<String, List<ClientBehavior>> behaviors = getClientBehaviors();
    if (behaviors.isEmpty()) {
        return;
    }


    if (behaviorEvent != null) {
        List<ClientBehavior> behaviorsForEvent = behaviors.get(behaviorEvent);
        if (behaviors.size() > 0) {
            String behaviorSource = params.get("javax.faces.source");
            String clientId = getClientId(context);
            if (behaviorSource != null && behaviorSource.equals(clientId)) {
                for (ClientBehavior behavior: behaviorsForEvent) {
                    behavior.decode(context, this);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


public Integer getSlider() {
    return (Integer) getStateHelper().eval(PropertyKeys.slider, null);
}

public void setSlider(Integer slider) {
    getStateHelper().put(PropertyKeys.slider, slider);
}   

private static final Collection<String> EVENT_NAMES = Collections.unmodifiableCollection(Arrays.asList(EVENT_VALUE_CHANGE));

@Override
public Collection<String> getEventNames() {
    return EVENT_NAMES;    
}

@Override
public String getDefaultEventName() {
  return EVENT_VALUE_CHANGE;    
}
```

}

The managed Bean (Mybean) with a listener

```
@ViewScoped
```

@ManagedBean
public class MyBean implements Serializable   {

```
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

Integer value = 1;

public void changeInterval(AjaxBehaviorEvent e)
{
    //AjaxBehavior behavior = (AjaxBehavior) e.getBehavior();
    SliderComponent componet = (SliderComponent) e.getComponent();
    value= componet.getSlider();
}


public Integer getGrouper  ( ) {

    return value;   
}


public void setGrouper (Integer value  ) {
    this.value = value;
}
```

}